# Change the radius and resolution of instanced circles per instance

Tags: geometry-nodes

I needed to make a centric circular array for an assignment.
My idea was to instance circles with increasing resolution and radius and instance cylinders on the vertices of those circles. I tried and tried to change those values but I could not get any results at all.

Since time was short, I manually created 50 or something circles with increasing resolution and radius.

Since I have some spare time now, i tried it one more time, looking through tutorials and using google. No results.

So back to the question:
**Is it possible to access and change the radius and the resolution of a curve circle per instance?**

Thanks and all the best!

This is the final result for a better understanding.

[image: Render result circular centric array]

Comment: You can change the radius individually via their scale, either directly from the Scale socket of "Instance on Points" node, or with a "Scale Instances" node after. But changing the resolution of one would mean changing the mesh of it, which would also change all other instances—after all, that's what an instance is.

Comment: It is possible to access attributes from destinct instances via the index node and the values of the spreadsheet, but I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate a line and move its points into circles based on point index. This is my attempt:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I check your solution as soon as I'm on my workstation!

Answer (score 7):

> Is it possible to access and change the radius and the resolution of a
> curve circle per instance?

Yes. Radius immediately, resolution after realization. You can do something like:

- Create a 0-length line with [the desired number of rings] points
- Instance  a Curve Circle (your rings) on all those points, scaled by a function of instance-index
- Realize the instances, and resample by [dot-interval] length
- Instance the dots on the resampled circles.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, I chose your solution. Worked like a charm, very flexible