# Scaling a specific face or face group in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Im trying to make a circular wood flooring but i just cant figure out a way to only scale a part of the mesh
[image: what im doing]

Set Position is able to read and modify the specific face that i want but i has no scaling option.
[image]

Comment: Can you give an idea of the result you're aiming for? Do you want wedge-shaped tiles? Best-fit rectangular tiles?

Comment: wedge-shaped. i want to scale either the inner or outer area

Answer (score 4):

Maybe not a direct answer to your question, but rather than go to the trouble of scaling the inside of a tile to a calculated different degree than the outside, you might just convert a circle to a mesh, with a line-profile, which creates wedge-shaped faces naturally.

Then you can split the edges. Once split, you can offset the vertices towards their face-centers, thus:

[image]

The distribution of tiles on rings is similar to [this method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/258293/35559). Concentric rings are instanced:

[image]

.. and  given a curve-line profile to create radially divided rings...

[image]

.. whose faces are split before being inset, as shown in the cluster in the top illustration, with this sort of result, after extrusion:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This solution doesn't allow me to instance a mesh, with uv, textures, etc. i have been able to kind of achieve what i want by setting the faces to smooth and then making the selection on "Scale elements" "shade_smooth". Very limiting but it gets the job done i guess. I cant seam to find a way to add a attribute to a face

Comment: Hi @Fall! at first sight, these are not instances, if you want them to fit.. the shape has to change according to ring-radius. How much irregularity would you be happy with? Is there more than one shape of tile?

Answer (score 0):

@Robin Betts

I realised that scaling a face or multiple faces would not work for a more complex geometry since the rest of the faces would not scale accordingly to have that wedge shaped that i wanted. I decided to pretty much do a array and a curve modifier in geometry nodes.[image: result]

The curve node is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYXeqwqauzE&t=1s&ab_channel=BlenderBash

I think the node is really bloated for what i need it to do but i don't have the expertise to remove the unnecessary parts without braking the whole thing.

The ideal solution would be to transform each of the objects in the collection and then distribute them around a curve so you dont have to realize them but i can not get it to work in reverse.